# Virtual Machine running out of disk space when there is still space left

Tags: vmware-workstation

I am currently running Fedora inside a VM on a Windows box using VMware Workstation. I allocated about 6GB for the Fedora VM.

Under VM settings, I see:

- Current size 3.6 GB
- Maximum size 6 GB
- System free 10 GB

Now Fedora is complaining it is running out of disk space. I see that VM disk file is only taking exactly 3.6 GB and not the complete allocated 6 GB.

Ouput of df is : /dev/mapper/vm_lv-root 3612384 3420160 15536 96%

I tried extending using vmware disk manager, which effectively increased my partition from 5 (originally) to 6 still same issue persists.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Please post the output of the "df" command as an edit to your question.

Comment: /dev/mapper/vm_lv-root 3612384 3420160 15536 96%

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible that Fedora has partitioned your virtual disk in such a way that one of the partitions is full, while another is near empty, and so leaving you with 2.4GB effectively unusable.

From what I know of Linux patition schemes I would expect your partition scheme to be something like:

- 200MB /Boot
- 512MB - 1GB Swap
- 2GB / (Root)
- 3GB /home (user files)

If you have filled up the home partition and the root partition only takes up a half gig then you would see the "disk full" error on your home partition while a good proportion of the disk is empty.

Some Linux distributiond I've seen do not use this kind of partition scheme at all and have only root and swap partitions which gets away from the problems you are seeing.

I don't know if VMWare supports resizing disk images but I would not be surprised if you could simply find the disk image in the VM settings and tell the software you want it to be larger.

If it is that simple then after you have done that you'll need to download a [GParted LiveCD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php), attach it to the VM and then get it to boot from the liveCD.  GParted should be able to resize and, if necessary, move the partitions within the VM.  It should show you which partition is nearly full and so be able to tell which one you need to resize.

As always though, back up your VM files before you start.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the details in the question, extending it did not help :(

Comment: You've extended the *disk* in the VM manager, you'll then need to extend the *partition* within the virtual machine itself.  For that I'd recommend trying GParted as I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks will give that a go. What still troubles me is the fact that if the entire installation is using ~5 gigs , i should see the same on my host operating system where vm ware is running. I still see it has files worth 3.6 gigs.

Comment: Ricko, df (1) doesn't show space available on the *disk*. It shows space available on *mounted partitions*. For some reason you have your VM set up with several gigs of unused virtual disk space.

Comment: Thanks carl. Is there any command which shows all drives available & space associated with them ? I am unable to boot with gpart via vm , it goes straight to the os..sigh!

Comment: Isn't there a key (F12 or something) that you can hold down while starting the VM to tell it to boot from the CD-ROM?