# VMWare disk space differs with actual disk space

Tags: vmware, ubuntu-12.04

My situation is the opposite of [Virtual Machine running out of disk space when there is still space left](https://superuser.com/questions/277113/virtual-machine-running-out-of-disk-space-when-there-is-still-space-left). I have an Ubuntu VM which was allocated 16GB. The VM became terribly slow recently and on checking the VMWare client showed only 20MB left. The result of running `df` however shows 2.9GB left. Why the difference?

Comment: How much physical disk space is available on the partition where the VM guest image resides? It's possible you've run out of physical hard drive space and the VM can't expand it's virtual disk any further.